# How to add "Nomenclature" in "sn-article" Springer through winedt?

Tags: positioning, natbib, glossaries, nomenclature, makeindex

The problem: How to add a "Nomenclature" section for Springer journals in a 1-column format at the after abstract and before introduction?
So, I googled a lot for this problem and finally did not found a solution. I'm sharing my code here maybe it helps someone in future to save time.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls -t \jobname.nlg}
\documentclass[referee,sn-standardnature]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$E$}{elastic constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried several methods to solve the Nomenclature generation, but there is an issue with compiling.

1. Using package nomencl with its \makenomenclature and \printnomenclature clearly doesn't work with "sn-jnl.cls"
2. In Makeindex box under Commands, added "makeindex .nlo -s nomencl.ist -o .els", but compiler gives error log " Zero entries added in %.nls file.
3. Tried to change the build sequence pdflatex-->makeindex-->pdflatex-->bibtex... But did not work.
4. Tried including packages like index, glossaries with their make and print commands, but still did not work.

Solution I found: build the nomenclature on a different latex template, copy the contents of that *.nls file into the sn-article.nls file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).